# Handling 404/4xx/5xx errors in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, error-handling, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.4.10 and I do have problem with correct error 4xx/5xx handling to get users to my custom html.

On **production**, when 500 error occurs, I'm getting this kind of screen:

[image]

Which is weird, because I followed this tutorial: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

I have my templates overridden (like here),[image] but still above screen occurs. (adding `error500.html.twig` file isn't changing anything)

When I'm debuging on **dev** it's ok, I mean, with this custom "_error" route.

What can be the problem here?

404 errors and sometimes work, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the documentation and your shared code, you are right.

Have you got clear cache dev and production environment ?

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Hello, yes I did. Many times.